# Pandas: How do I get aggregate value changes between columns?

Tags: python, pandas

So, given a dataframe as follows:

```
Item    Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
Apple       3       4       3       4
Orange      5       6       1       2
```

I need to identify change in value (increase/decrease) on each product, over the four quarters, and aggregate these fluctuations for each quarter.

- If the value goes up one quarter compared to the previous quarter, I need to add the increase to an aggregated value `Up` for that quarter.
- If it goes down, I need to record it as `Down` for that quarter.

Desired output:

```
Type                Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
Up                      0      2       0        2
Down                    0      0       6        0
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not really about 'values' but 'changes in value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
diff = df.set_index('Item').diff(axis=1).sum(axis=0)
new_df = (pd.DataFrame([
            np.where(diff.ge(0), diff, 0),
            np.where(diff.lt(0), abs(diff), 0)
        ],
        index=['Up', 'Down'],
        columns=diff.index
    )
    .astype(int))
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
      Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
Up         0       2       0       2
Down       0       0       6       0
```

#### Explanation

First, we compute the diff:

```
>>> diff = df.set_index('Item').diff(axis=1).sum(axis=0)
>>> diff
Jan_20    0.0
Apr_20    2.0
Aug_20   -6.0
Oct_20    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Next, we extract the positive values into one array and the negative values into another:

```
>>> pos = np.where(diff.ge(0), diff, 0)
>>> pos
array([0., 2., 0., 2.])

>>> neg = np.where(diff.lt(0), abs(diff), 0)
>>> neg
array([0., 0., 6., 0.])
```

Then, we create a dataframe using those two arrays:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([pos, neg])
     0    1    2    3
0  0.0  2.0  0.0  2.0
1  0.0  0.0  6.0  0.0
```

But since it's not that useful without column names and row labels, we add those in while we create the dataframe:

```
>>> diff.index
Index(['Jan_20', 'Apr_20', 'Aug_20', 'Oct_20'], dtype='object')

# Set the row labels:
>>> pd.DataFrame([pos, neg], index=['Up', 'Down'])
        0    1    2    3
Up    0.0  2.0  0.0  2.0
Down  0.0  0.0  6.0  0.0

# Now the columns:
>>> pd.DataFrame([pos, neg], columns=diff.index)
   Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
0     0.0     2.0     0.0     2.0
1     0.0     0.0     6.0     0.0

# Now both:
>>> pd.DataFrame([pos, neg], index=['Up', 'Down'], columns=diff.index)
      Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
Up       0.0     2.0     0.0     2.0
Down     0.0     0.0     6.0     0.0
```

Finally, we create the datatype, and also make the values ints by passing `dtype=int` to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([pos, neg], index=['Up', 'Down'], columns=diff.index, dtype=int)
>>> df
      Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
Up         0       2       0       2
Down       0       0       6       0
```

Comment: this one works! But I'm actually not sure I entirely understand the way new_df is created. What is the logic here?

Comment: Sure, it's simple. I'll add an explanation in the answer.

Comment: @Zaphod check the answer now. Added a nice explanation :)

Comment: Great! When creating the first dataframe `diff`what is the use of `set_index('Item')`I've tried running it without that and that also works.

Answer (score 0):

To get **differences** between columns, use pandas `.diff(axis=1)`:

```
dd = df.diff(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

        Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
Item                                  
Apple        0       1      -1       1
Orange       0       1      -5       1
```

Then to get the **aggregates for positive/negative** we can use `dd.where(dd>0, 0).sum()` to get 'Up':

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records({'Up': dd.where(dd>0, 0).sum(), 'Down': -dd.where(dd<0, 0).sum()}).transpose()

      Jan_20  Apr_20  Aug_20  Oct_20
Down       0       0       6       0
Up         0       2       0       2
```

(pandas gave us an unwanted sort of the row index in alphabetical order, you can trivially fix that)